# Why do I get 128 teams/thread blocks and 96 threads in each teams/thread blocks using #pragma omp target team distribute parallel for in OpenMP?

Tags: openmp, nvidia, clang++

I am running this code on Ubuntu 18.04, clang/llvm compiler with Nvidia GTX 1070 GPU

```
#pragma omp target data map(to: A,B) map(from: C)
{
   #pragma omp target teams distribute
   for(int n=0; n<Row; n++)
   {
   int team_id= omp_get_team_num();
   #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(auto)
   for(int j = 0; j <Col; j++)
   {
       int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
           printf("Iteration= c[ %d ][ %d ], Team=%d, Thread=%d\n",n, j, team_id, thread_id);
       C[n][j] = A[n][j] + B[n][j];
   }

   }
}
```

in the above code, max value of team is 127 and thread is 95

compile flags: clang++ -fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -Xopenmp-target -march=sm_61 -Wall -O3 debug.cpp -o debug

Comment: That should be ok, as the numbering starts from 0, so if you get 127 as the maximum team ID, then you have 128 teams.  Same for the threads, numbering is from 0 to n-1.

Comment: My motivations of this question: the max thread per block for gtx1070 is 1024, there are 128 cores/SM, so the number of threads should be at least 128, but it's showing only 96 by default.

Comment: What if you add a `num_teams` and a `thread_limit` clause?